# Why this error happens in ReactJS using axios

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

```
export const signUp=(email, phone, password)=> {
return {
    type: "SIGN_UP",
    promise: axios.post(`${API_URL}auth/register`,
        {
            email:email,
            phone:phone,
            password:password
        },
        {
    headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    }
    ),


}
```

Here is the action, where I have to send the body(with parameters). However, the error happens.[image]

Comment: have you tried making the same post request with curl, or Postman? I would approach this by first removing React from the equation and doing a sanity check. Also, do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: Well, what is the error? copy and paste the whole error...

Comment: but probably, the server is not configured for CORS

Comment: I think it might be CORS settings - try the same request from curl to test it.